# Can I connect 2 outlets to one Existing outlet?>

Tags: wiring

Can I connect two outlets to an outlet that is connected to the power source? example: Outlet 1 is connected to a power source. Outlet 2 is connected to outlet 1. now I want to connect outlet 3 to outlet 2 or do I need to split it into a electrical box? TYA

exmaple
https://ibb.co/YPV61ZL

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box you plan to make the split at please?

Comment: Hi it may be necessary to replace the box with a deeper or bigger box to prevent overloading the box especially if you are using hard wire, and a heavy gauge. Only so many connections are allowed in a box. Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routing wise, this can be done with a surface conduit system like Legrand Wiremold. This has an "extension box" that screws to the surface of the wall, and then you extend surface conduit off the side of that extension box.

Box fill wise, you will need additional cubic inches in the box to accommodate the additional wires. You will need to do a box fill calculation for the box and make sure it's big enough.  If it's not,  you can buy some additional cubic inches by using the Legrand Wiremold extension box earlier mentioned.

Box fill calculations require 2 cubic inches per #14 wire, 2.25 cubic inches per #12 wire (and you must use #12 if the breaker is 20A), and special rules:

- grounds are "4 for the price of 1"
- if cable clamps intrude into the box, all of them count as 1 "wire" of the largest size
- receptacles and switches count as 2 "wires" each (of largest size)

Wire connection wise, you can either pigtail, or use $3 "spec grade" receptacles whose instructions state a method for attaching 2 wires per screw terminal (so four on a common receptacle).

Answer (score 0):

If you can fit the connections (wire nuts, push connectors etc) into existing outlet safely - yes.
Use a wire gauge same or bigger as the one in the existing outlet.
The only limit may be the total load on given breaker - some countries have limit how many outlets you can have on single breaker. Remember that new outlet still draws from same line, so it doesn't magically increase the total amount of power you can draw.